# Get HTML DOM elements inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement something like this. IF you click the button it would get the HTML of the above elements and insert them in an alert :

```
<div id="0001">

    <h5 class="title">Hello World </h5>
    <h4 class="date">2014-07-19 </h4>

    <button onclick="addCalendar('#0001. #title','#0001. #date')"> Add to Calendar </button>
</div>    

<div id="0002">

    <h5 class="title">Bye Bye</h5>
    <h4 class="date">2014-07-22 </h4>

    <button onclick="addCalendar('#0002. #title','#0002. #date')"> Add to Calendar </button>
</div>

<script>
function addCalendar(title,date){
    alert(title + ": " + date);   
}
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by getting `HTML` full like this `<h5 id="title">Hello World </h5>`

Comment: **note**: id should be unique

Comment: @Grundy yes of course

Comment: in your sample you have two elements with same id :-)

Comment: but `h5` and `h4` id - not

Comment: An ID should be unique for the page. If you need to repeat a selector, the convention is to use a class.

Comment: @DivinusVox yes i have changed my code and the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should works..

If you want to get the value of that HTML:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).siblings("#title").text();
    value += $(this).siblings("#date").text();
    alert(value);
});
```

If you want to get the HTML tags too:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).siblings("#title").html();
    value += $(this).siblings("#date").html();
    alert(value);
});
```